# Display Count of posts inside of a custom taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, foreach, taxonomy-terms

So, I have this page attached and have currently got a list outputting each Term where a post is contained in a particular term.

To do this I have a custom post type called 'episodes'

I have a custom Taxonomy called 'episode_categories'

and inside this I have various terms such as VR, Mixed Martial Arts and so on.

What I want to do is show a count of each term that has X amount of posts in it.

I currently have this as my code.

```
<div class="placeholder-main relative py-64 md:py-56 min-h-screen flex">
    <div class="main my-auto w-full flex:none">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="categories flex flex-wrap xs:block">
                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'type'                     => 'episodes',
                        'post_status'              => 'publish',
                        'child_of'                 => 0,
                        'parent'                   => '',
                        'orderby'                  => 'name',
                        'order'                    => 'ASC',
                        'hide_empty'               => 1,
                        'hierarchical'             => 1,
                        'taxonomy'                 => 'episode_categories',
                        'pad_counts'               => false
                    );

                    $categories = get_categories($args);
                    ?>
                    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
                        <div class="categories__item w-1/2 xs:w-full pr-5 xs:p-0 mt-10 xs:mt-6">
                            <div class="article text-2xl sm:text-xl xxs:text-base">
                                <h2 class="text-4xl sm:text-28px xxs:text-xl font-bold leading-none"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($category); ?>" class="transition ease-out duration-300 hover:opacity-50"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></h2>
                                <p>There are
                                    <strong>
                                        0
                                    </strong> podcasts in this category
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the function `get_categories` returns the number of posts each category are associated to. You can access this value through `category_count`. Here is the code :

```
<p>
    <strong>
        <?= $category->category_count; ?>
    </strong>
</p>
```

Tested and works

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mathias. This is great thank you very much, however it still doesnt seem right.  My business category for example has 2 episodes attached to it, with your code it still counts 1 episode for business.

Comment: Maybe you need to reset the postdata of the second query. I updated my post, tell me if it works

Comment: Hi Mathias, could you write out an example, not 100% I am putting the code in the right place but I still get the same results even when resetting.

Comment: Hi Glen, I found a better solution to achieve it. I've tested this one and it works well for me, tell me if it works for you as well!

Comment: My God how crazy, I have looked everywhere across Stack Overflow, Forums and they were attempting alll kinds of solutions with WP Query, lengthy code and it seems you can do it in under 30 characters! Thats working for me too Mathias. Thanks ever so much for getting back to me quickly.